# string to time parsing and diff analysis

Tags: c++, c

I want to parse a string to time and get the diff of 2 such time. for example "15:01:14.394" and "15:01:14.785". There are lot of c++ library but I am confused which can exactly help me here to get accuracy upto millisecond. 
Dear friends, plz guide me here.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also please refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). In short, asking for links to libraries is off-topic.

Comment: C++20 got it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie unfortunately only down to second resolution. There's also [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), which have the same problem (no milliseconds).

Comment: Pick a language. C != C++, particularly when it comes to libraries.

Comment: Hello friend, sry for inconvenience. I am processing a log for which I need to parse a time format like "2020-02-25 15:01:14.395" and calculate the diff of two such times till millisecond level. I am writing the program in c++, any solution will work here. I mean both c or c++. Thats way I chose the tag as c or c++.  Friends plz help me here if someone knows the answer. thanks in advance